# Setting the primary key directly via the Key ID property is not supported - Spanner database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, spring-data-rest, google-cloud-spanner

I'm having an issue doing put and patch operations on the following code.

Repository Code

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "students", path = "students") 
public interface StudentRepository extends SpannerRepository<Student, Key> { }
```

```
@Table(name = "STUDENT") 
public class Student 
{ 
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Id of the Student", required = true) 
    @PrimaryKey @Column(name = "STUD_ID") 
    private String studentId; 

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Courses", required = true) 
    @Column(name = "COURSES") 
    private List<Course> course; 

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Institute name", required = true) 
    @Column(name = "NAME") 
    private String instituteName; 
}
```

Stack trace below:

```
**org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.spanner.core.mapping.SpannerDataException: Setting the primary key directly via the Key ID property is not supported. Please set the underlying column properties.
    at** org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.spanner.core.mapping.SpannerPersistentEntityImpl$1.setProperty(SpannerPersistentEntityImpl.java:382) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.lambda$resolveArgument$2(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:143) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver$$Lambda$1311/453444314.accept(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:143) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:165) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:154) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:122) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_40]
```

Comment: Repository Code

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "students", path = "students")
public interface StudentRepository extends SpannerRepository<Student, Key> { 
}

Comment: @Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Id of the Student", required = true)
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(name = "STUD_ID")
    private String studentId;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Courses", required = true)
    @Column(name = "COURSES")
    private List<Course> course;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Institute name", required = true)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String instituteName;
}

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct syntax? Check out this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/_spring_data_spanner.html#_primary_keys) from the official documentation.

Comment: @sllopis : yes I'm, I did refer to the same document. In fact POST, GET and DELETE actions are working fine. Just that PUT and PATCH is having issues as mentioned above in the stack trace.

Comment: Hi @GopalGowda, the SpannerDataException message you are seeing is related to the `setProperty()` method, as you can see in the [Official Github Repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/spanner/core/mapping/SpannerPersistentEntityImpl.java). My hypothesis is that you may need to set the column properties by using a constructor when using object mapping. Example 
[here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-gcp.html#_object_mapping).

Comment: Hi @sllopis, I know the class and the method which is causing the issue but still couldn't understand and nail it down to the root cause and I also tried to set the columns by using a constructor that didn't help as well.

Answer (score 1):

GopalGowda, I'm from team that works on that module.

Can you share the code where you're setting the ID value? 
I suspect it might be that you're directly setting the ID property rather than just the studentId property as it were a regular property.

The reason is that under the hood the ID property is actually a hidden Key value that is there to support composite keys and other Spanner functionality.

Comment: Hi somegcpjavahelp, I have shared the code in my query above, it is just an entity and a spanner repository what is required for the spring data rest project. After that I'm doing a PUT request with the payload {"instituteName":"PESIT"} and the request URI http://localhost:8080/spannerproject/students/101010. Full stack trace is also copied above.

Comment: Gopal, thanks much for that detail. It appears this might be something that needs a fix then. Please follow this issue on the github repository: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/2044

Comment: Thank you so much. Please note this issue is observed for both put and patch operations. When can I expect this issue to be fixed ? Thanks again!

Comment: @GopalGowda, the fix has been committed :)

Comment: Should I be using 1.1.4 release version ? Here is what I'm using which didn't work <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
  </properties>

Comment: Please use the newly released 1.2.0.RELEASE.